# JSONCPP Not reading files correctly

Tags: c++, json

So I recently installed JSONCPP and for some reason it gives me errors when I try this code:

```
#include <json.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    bool alive = true;
    while (alive){
    Json::Value root;   // will contains the root value after parsing.
    Json::Reader reader;
    std::string test = "testis.json";
    bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( test, root, false );
    if ( !parsingSuccessful )
    {
        // report to the user the failure and their locations in the document.
        std::cout  << reader.getFormatedErrorMessages()
               << "\n";
    }

    std::string encoding = root.get("encoding", "UTF-8" ).asString();
    std::cout << encoding << "\n";
    alive = false;


    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the file:

```
{
"encoding" : "lab"
}
```

It says that there is a syntax error on Line 1, Column 1, and that there must be a value, object or array. Anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: Changed to current code, from pastebin

Comment: To format your code, select it and press CTRL+K. Use the preview.

Comment: Downvote is because: simply _read the documentation_ instead of randomly guessing at function arguments, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit actually, the documentation for this argument reads _"UTF-8 encoded string containing the document to read."_ which is at least a bit ambiguous as one could infer from the word 'document' being used that the std::string requested should indeed be a file path. In fact, I just made the same mistake as the OP.

Comment: @Tom: A document isn't a path to a document; it's a document! I concede the documentation could be extra clear for people who don't know what "document" means ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See the [`Json::Reader::parse`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_reader.html#f1da6c976ad1e96c742804c3853eef94) documentation.  For that overload, the string needs to be the actual document, not the filename.

You can use the [istream overload](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_reader.html#8d0347e6b47343e4bc68be7ecdb9c4e9) with a `ifstream` instead.

```
std::ifstream test("testis.json", std::ifstream::binary);
```

EDIT: I got it work with:

```
#include "json/json.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    bool alive = true;
    while (alive){
    Json::Value root;   // will contains the root value after parsing.
    Json::Reader reader;
    std::ifstream test("testis.json", std::ifstream::binary);
    bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( test, root, false );
    if ( !parsingSuccessful )
    {
        // report to the user the failure and their locations in the document.
        std::cout  << reader.getFormatedErrorMessages()
               << "\n";
    }

    std::string encoding = root.get("encoding", "UTF-8" ).asString();
    std::cout << encoding << "\n";
    alive = false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error. How do you make it the actual document?

Comment: @Yelnats, I've now tested the above with your input file.

Comment: This is crazy, this isn't working for me. I place the testis.json file in the directory of the project right? so it'll be C:\Programs\TestJSON\TestJSON right?

Comment: @Yelnats, no, it has to be the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) where you start the program.  That's the same *if* you're in that directory when you run the program (e.g. `./testis.json` is the JSON file, then you enter `./TestJSON` to run the program).  Also, you should edit the question with your current code.  Just to simplify the test, you can try putting `C:\\Programs\\TestJSON\\TestJSON\\testis.json`.

Comment: I can't get the code to be displayed correctly in the question, because when I press tab to create code spans, it just tabs down into the tags. http://cpp.pastebin.com/JWhRKt3r Oh and I've put it into the every possible directory and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Yelnats, a few things.  Try an absolute path (see previous comment) for testing purposes.  Also, I note that you're missing `alive = false`, so your loop is infinite.  Finally, you can use Ctrl-K or the 101 button on the toolbar to format code.

Comment: @Yelnats, just in case, what version of JSONCPP are you using?  I compiled it out of SVN (r152).

Comment: Recompiled out of SVN just now and still getting the same error. Maybe I am not using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @Yelnats, if you want, you can email me (see my profile) the JSON file you're using.  I am testing with a UTF-8 (also ASCII) file.

Comment: Oh god I remade the file from scrap and it works. Thanks a lot for all the help and I'm sorry about this part.

Comment: Oh crap how do I change the values and write them into the .json file? Or even make new values for that matter. The documentation talks about "styledwriter" but all that seems to do is write to std::strings or streams, not the file itself.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include "json/json.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    Json::Value root;   // will contain the root value after parsing.
    std::ifstream stream("testis.json", std::ifstream::binary);
    stream >> root;
    std::string encoding = root.get("encoding", "UTF-8" ).asString();
    std::cout << encoding << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Or more generally:

```
#include "json/json.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    Json::Value root;   // will contain the root value after parsing.
    Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
    std::ifstream test("testis.json", std::ifstream::binary);
    std::string errs;
    bool ok = Json::parseFromStream(builder, test, &root, &errs);
    if ( !ok )
    {
        // report to the user the failure and their locations in the document.
        std::cout  << errs << "\n";
    }

    std::string encoding = root.get("encoding", "UTF-8" ).asString();
    std::cout << encoding << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/namespace_json.html

Answer (score -13):

json cannot contain newlines. Try this instead:

```
{"encoding": "lab"}
```

You may need to ensure the file is saved without a final newline.

**EDIT**: Maybe your parser tolerates newlines, but some don't. Something to try if the other answers don't work

Comment: Yes it can, and this isn't the issue.  Any parser that says otherwise should be scrapped.  [RFC 4627](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627): "Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six structural characters."  And the definition of whitespace explicitly includes both CR and LF.

Comment: JSON can absolutely contain newlines. What nonsense.